# Codeigniter 3 blog application: how can I avoid redundancy of static data?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8.

I have a model with "static" data like the website's title, the contact email address, etc:

```
class Static_model extends CI_Model {
    public function get_static_data() {
        $data['site_title'] = "My Blog";
        $data['tagline'] = "A simple blog application made with Codeigniter 3";
        $data['company_name'] = "My Company";
        $data['company_email'] = "company@domain.com";
        return $data;
    }
}
```

In my Posts Controller, which handles both the *posts* page and the *single post* page, I was forced to load the Static_model **twice**:

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Static_model');
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();

        $this->load->model('Posts_model');
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts();

        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('posts');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }

    public function post($id) {
        $this->load->model('Static_model');
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();

        $this->load->model('Posts_model');
        $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);

        // Overwrite the default tagline with the post title
        $data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;

        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('post');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }

}
```

As you can see, the *header* and *footer* partials ware also loaded redundantly.

**Questions:**

1. How can I load the Static_model only *once* and so that both the
   index() *and* post() methods can use it?
2. Also, how can I load the partials only once per controller?

Thanks!

Comment: you can define method for these in custom helper and call it directly to your views

Comment: Is there a better way that I could structure my controller?

Comment: no need to involve any controller or model ,it is a better way if u have all static data , i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the model in the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Static_model');
}
```

Since the constructor gets called every time the class is instantiated, it will always be available to any methods called later.

Regarding the views, you can use `require()` or `include()` as usual to load partials from the view file.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir To be honest I haven't used Codeigniter since 2014 (switched to Laravel) so you might be better off waiting for someone else to answer

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to obtain a controller configuration hat is a lot closer to the being optimal then the initial one:

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();

    // Load static data
    $this->load->model('Static_model');
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        // Load Header
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Posts_model');
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts();
        $this->load->view('posts', $data);
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }

    public function post($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('Posts_model');
        $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);
        // Overwrite the default tagline with the post title
        $data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;
        $this->load->view('post', $data);
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }

}
```

The line `$this->load->view('partials/footer');` still appears in both functions, but I am closer to respecting the DRY principle.

This configuration of the controller has solved a problem and created another: the line `$data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;` has no effect now.

Comment: It probably makes sense to load all of your models in the constructor - I don't use CodeIgniter any more, but when I did it was easier to load them all there. Anything else that's needed in more than one method, it's probably a good idea to deal with in the constructor and assign it to a property. Loading views does tend to get a bit repetitive in CodeIgniter, unfortunately, as there's no easy way to extend a view like you can with Twig or Laravel's Blade.