# Codeigniter 3 blog application: overwriting default "static" variable with a "dynamic" one fails

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8.

I have a model with "static" data like the website's title, the contact email address, etc:

```
class Static_model extends CI_Model {
    public function get_static_data() {
        $data['site_title'] = "My Blog";
        $data['tagline'] = "A simple blog application made with Codeigniter 3";
        $data['company_name'] = "My Company";
        $data['company_email'] = "company@domain.com";
        return $data;
    }
}
```

In my Posts Controller, I have tried to flow the DRY principle this way:

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
      // Load static data
      $this->load->model('Static_model');
      $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
      // Load Header
      $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Posts_model');
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts();
        $this->load->view('posts', $data);
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }

    public function post($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('Posts_model');
        $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);

        if (!empty($data['post'])) {
            // Overwrite the default tagline with the post title
            $data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;
        } else {
            $data['tagline'] = "Page not found";
            show_404();
        }

        $this->load->view('post', $data);
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }

}
```

See details of how I came about writing the code above in **[this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49705743/4512005)**.

The problem with the above code is that the line `$data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;` does no longer overwrite the static tagline `$data['tagline'] = "A simple blog application made with Codeigniter 3";` with the post title. It did overwrite it when the controller look like this:

class Posts extends CI_Controller {

```
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Static_model');
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();

        $this->load->model('Posts_model');
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts();

        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('posts');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }

    public function post($id) {
        $this->load->model('Static_model');
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();

        $this->load->model('Posts_model');
        $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);

        // Overwrite the default tagline with the post title
        $data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;

        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('post');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }

}
```

Bot this old version of it is goes against the DRY principle.

How can I do the desired overwrite without breaking the "DRY commandment"?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error, it is just that `$data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;` does no longer work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a new property:

`$this->_data` or `$this->staticData` instead of `$data`

You will then be able to access/update the object property within your class.

static variable **cannot** be accessed outside the existing method/function

That's why when you try to update `$data['tagline']` with new value, this will work but only withing your `public function post($id)`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Example:

```
$data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
```

to

```
$this->data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
```

Then

```
$this->data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);
$this->data['tagline'] = $this->data['post']->title;
```

**EDITED**

Answer (score 0):

Assign global variable in your model.

```
class Static_model extends CI_Model {

    public $taglinge= "A simple blog application made with Codeigniter 3";
    public function get_static_data() {
        $data['site_title'] = "My Blog";
        $data['tagline'] = $this->tagline;
        $data['company_name'] = "My Company";
        $data['company_email'] = "company@domain.com";
        return $data;
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public function post($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('Posts_model');
        $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($id);

        if (!empty($data['post'])) {
            // Overwrite the default tagline with the post title
            $this->Static_model->tagline = $data['post']->title;
        } else {
            $data['tagline'] = "Page not found";
            show_404();
        }

        $this->load->view('post', $data);
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }
```

Comment: I already have this varianle:  `$data['tagline'] = "A simple blog application made with Codeigniter 3";` in the Model. I want to overwrite it.

Comment: See in your model what I did

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$taglinge' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in path/to/file`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168454/discussion-between-gulmuhammad-akbari-and-razvan-zamfir).